# Minimal standalone install of Microsoft Device Emulator

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, device-emulator-manager

I have installed the Microsoft Device Emulator 3.0 and the Windows Mobile 6.5 DTK on a clean Windows 7 system. From the Start menu, I can start an emulator.

However, the Device Emulator Manager does not show any of the emulators, so it is impossible to Connect and Cradle the emulator.

How can I install apps to the emulator using the Windows Mobile Device Center in this case?

(I realize installing Visual Studio would probably solve the issue - I'm interesting in doing this without VS.)

Comment: This is more something for superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Device Emulator Manager will not show a list of installed Emulators.

However, if you have an Emulator started, it will appear as a GUID number. Right click on that, and you can cradle the device.

Make sure you have ActiveSync/Windows Mobile Device Center set to allow connections via DMA.